# if input field number value equal 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write if input value = 0 hide div.class else show div.class

this is what i tried, but only have of it seems to be working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("input.product-quantity").val() == 0) {
        $(".name-number-field-container").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".name-number-field-container").show();
    }
});
```

to add an on change I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-quantity').change(function() {
    var $cont = $('.name-number-field-container');
      if($(this).val() === '0'){
           $cont.hide();
      } else {
           $cont.show();
      }
     });
});
```

but no luck

Comment: Only on page load or whenever that input value changes?

Comment: This only runs once. Did you intend for it to run every time the input is changed?

Comment: change `0` to `"0"` and you should really use `===` over `==` for a quick fix

Comment: yes if the field goes back to 0 after being changed it should hide again and then show again if the value is greater than 0

Comment: javascript is event based, When you write an if statement like what you have, it only  happens once. If you want it to be re-evaluated, you have to hook it up to some event that will be triggered at the point in time you want it evaluated, in this case, either the change event or the blur event.

Comment: whenever the input changes

Comment: Where has `$cont` been assigned in your code?

Comment: @antony - haha i think she copied and pasted a portion of my code, i created that variable. I also did the `$(this).val()` thing, I think shes just missing the important piece of my answer.

Comment: @anmaree - so you changed your OP ... did you actually TRY my code? like ... the entire thing? cuz it works... I even included a jsFiddle to show that it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `.val()` is going to return a string, so eliminate implicit conversions:

```
$(function(){
    var $cont = $('.name-number-field-container'),
        $qty = $('.product-quantity');

    function setCont(val){
        if(val === '0'){
            $cont.hide();
        } else {
            $cont.show();
        }
    }

    $qty.on('keyup',function(){    
        setCont(this.value);
    });

    setCont($qty.val());
});
```

No need to `parseInt`, just compare strings. If you are REALLY worried about someone entering '00000' or something, then yes, use `parseInt`:

```
    $(function(){
    var $cont = $('.name-number-field-container'),
        $qty = $('.product-quantity');

    function setCont(val){
        if(parseInt(val,10) === 0){
            $cont.hide();
        } else {
            $cont.show();
        }
    }

    $qty.on('keyup',function(){    
        setCont(this.value);
    });

    setCont($qty.val());
});
```

But at that point you are unneedingly converting the value, so I would advise against this unless absolutely needed.

**Edited**: apparently no one notified you that you need to bind this to an event. I chose `keyup` to see the change right away, but you can just as easily use `blur` for when the `input` no longer has focus. I also switched it to `this.value`, as it is a crapton faster.

[Here is a jsFiddle to show the string compare working](http://jsfiddle.net/B8CX4/), and [here is a jsFiddle to show the parseInt compare working](http://jsfiddle.net/B8CX4/1/).

**Edited again**: please explain IN DETAIL what the problem you are facing is, other than "it still doesn't work. I have updated my answers to show how to call BOTH on page load and by keyup.

Or ... crazy thought ... you just set it in CSS:

```
.name-number-field-container {
    display:none;
}
```

Then you don't need to do it all in Javascript. Either way will work.

[Here is the jsFiddle for the string](http://jsfiddle.net/B8CX4/3/), [here is the jsFiddle for the parseInt](http://jsfiddle.net/B8CX4/4/), and [here is the jsFiddle for the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/B8CX4/5/).

Comment: when I change the value to 1 the .name-number-field-container does not appear

Comment: I did try this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. it doesnt even hide the .name-number-field-containers at all.

Comment: @anmaree have you looked at my jsFiddle? because it works there. ive updated to have two jsFiddles now: one for the string compare, another for the `parseInt` compare.

Comment: i did see it. ok see whats happening. it works, but you see my value defaults as 0 and and so on page load the div still appears when I go back to 0 it hides

Comment: it also only works when I use .on('change'.. not keyup

Comment: @anmaree - please work on explaining in detail the cause of your problem. I have updated my answer to include firing the event on page load, as well as on change. and yes, it works on keyup, otherwise my working examples wouldn't work. they would be not working examples.

Comment: your right. I didn't realize that my question would get so complicated. thank you for your help

Comment: It makes *so* much sense that *my* answer got downvoted and *not* this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (parseInt($("input.product-quantity").val(), 10) === 0) {
        $(".name-number-field-container").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".name-number-field-container").show();
    }
});
```

should work.  Your code doesn't work because `val()` returns a **String,** and `parseInt()` returns the **integer** part of the **String.**

If you want to check by **String**, you could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("input.product-quantity").val() === '0') {
        $(".name-number-field-container").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".name-number-field-container").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use `===` instead of `==`. You may find it needs to be `=== "0"` after this and you don't need the `parseInt`

Comment: Never use `parseInt` without the second parameter. It might lead to very strange results :).

Comment: `parseInt($("input.product-quantity").val(), 10)`

Comment: What is the function of the second parameter?

Comment: Isn't this default 10 on all platforms? Why/how/when could it lead to strange results? (Just curious)

Comment: @MarkKnol Yes, but kapa says not to leave it blank

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `==` when making logic comparisons, it's better to use `===`. You eliminate the need for `parseInt` that way.
Because you're comparing the value of an input field, the field's datatype will be `string`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $input = $("input.product-quantity");
    var $field = $(".name-number-field-container");

    $field[($input.val() === "0" ? 'hide' : 'show')]();
});
```